# Button that Plays Sound in Android Studio not Playing

Tags: java, android, audio, android-studio

I am trying to make a simple button that plays a sound, but I am getting an error on `(this, R.raw.shotgun)`. I have the `raw` folder and the sound file. I think the problem is with the `this` but I don't know why. Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shotgun);
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter of MediaPlayer.create is a `Context`. The usage of `MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shotgun)` works when you are working in your `Activity`s scope, because `Activity` extends `Context`, therefore `this` in this case ends up being a `Context` as well.

However, you're working within `View.OnClickListener` scope, and `this` assumes this class' value, and not `Context` as required. To fix that, just set the Context variable to `this` while still in your Activity scope.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.shotgun);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: To be honest, I am super new to android studio and java. What is app context? @RafaelCardoso

Comment: @LUKER `Context` is a class that has many attributes required for diverse operations, such as accessing resources or creating new views.

Comment: So what would I put in the context part? @RafaelCardoso

Comment: Thank you for the help! Sorry, I didn't l see all of the changes in the code. I have one more question. How would I implement this into a button switch with multiple 'button.setOnClickListener(this)' ? I would imagine there would have to be some change in context. @RafaelCardoso